# Separate ClassLoader to Help Garbage Collection

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, classloader

Consider a java library consisting of "setup code" as opposed to run-time code.
The setup code can contain many classes defining menus with tables of options.
During the run-time of the application, the setup code would be invoked infrequently to perform tasks like changing a configuration property.

Are there merits to using code like the following?

```
public class Setup
{
    private static final class SetupClassLoader extends ClassLoader
    {   
        SetupClassLoader()
        {   
            super(Setup.class.getClassLoader());
        }   
    }   
    public static Setup getInstance() throws Exception
    {   
        SetupClassLoader scl = new SetupClassLoader();
        Class sc = scl.loadClass("com.example.Setup");
        return (Setup)sc.newInstance();
    }
    private ObjectWithLargeTablesOfData createObjectWithLargeTablesOfData()
    {
        ...
```

The idea is that when a Setup instance is no longer referenced, the garbage collector could more effectively release everything loaded by it because the ClassLoader itself could be collected.

If this method was not used, could setup code related class definitions linger in memory?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I can't imagine that a few setup-only classes could ever be a problem. And you don't need to imagine it either. You need to measure. Take a memory snapshot of an application that has been running for some time, and analyze it. I bet those classes will take less than 1% of the whole. Probably significantly less. Is that worth the added code complexity?

Comment: The setup classes contain a lot of tables of text and code that goes with the menu options. The size of the class files is comparable to all of the other classes. If it's not used 99.99% of the time, I would think they should be released. Unless this method just simply doesn't work as theorized or has a negative effect I'm not seeing.

Comment: "I would think they should be released" > Well, like I said: you should probably *test* that assumption before spending effort implementing a fix that won't gain much if anything.

Comment: If you want it to be released, set the object references to `null`. If it is referenced, it won't be GC'd, the `ClassLoader` doesn't change that.

Comment: There are a number of problems with this question that make it hard to understand what you are saying.  1) You are using "dereference" in a strange way.  The real meaning of "dereference" is to follow a pointer (reference) to the thing that it points to.  That doesn't make sense in this context.  2) Is "com.example.Setup" this `Setup` class or a different one?  3) What is the significance of `loadMenu`?  What calls it?  When?  4)  What does `com.example.Setup` do?  We need to see its code. That will determine whether there will be a memory leak involving the classloader.

Comment: Overall, I think this is a bad idea.  Generally speaking, setup code doesn't occupy much space ... unless it is effectively representing the data structures that you are setting up in the code itself.  And if *that* is what you are doing, you probably should be *loading* that initial data from a file or resource.

Comment: If you are not willing to show us (in effect) a minimal reproducible example to analyze, the best I can say is that it *might* work.   Whether it *does* work will depend on details that you haven't shown us.  And the best thing would be for you to just try it for yourself and see.   (And **measure** how much memory you saved ... so that you can decide whether it was *actually* worth the effort.)

Comment: Noting that it most likely won’t be—the runtime will clear the memory it can if it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand, is that runtime classes defined by different class loaders are different classes. [JVMS, §5.3. Creation and Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> After creation, a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2.1)) and its defining loader.

But it’s possible to recognize that there’s something odd with the following code, even without the specification:

> ```java
> public static Setup getInstance() throws Exception
> {   
>     SetupClassLoader scl = new SetupClassLoader();
>     Class sc = scl.loadClass("com.example.Setup");
>     return (Setup)sc.newInstance();
> }
> ```

This method has two reference to the class `Setup`, a type cast and the return type. If casting to `Setup` and returning the object as `Setup` works, the object’s type must be compatible with the `Setup` type referenced by this method, in other words, it can’t be a type defined by your custom class loader that could get garbage collected while this method (and presumably the caller too) have references to it.

The reason why this code does not fail, is that your class loader makes no attempt to define a `Setup` class at all. It simply follows the [standard delegation model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#:%7E:text=The%20ClassLoader%20class,or%20resource%20itself.)

> The `ClassLoader` class uses a delegation model to search for classes and resources. Each instance of `ClassLoader` has an associated parent class loader. When requested to find a class or resource, a `ClassLoader` instance will usually delegate the search for the class or resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the class or resource itself.

The `SetupClassLoader`’s parent loader is `Setup.class.getClassLoader()`, so obviously it has no problem finding the class when requested and this class defined by the parent loader is the class referenced by the calling code, so everything works fine. Except that this class can’t be unloaded and given the way the calling code uses the class, there is no way to change that without breaking the code.

In other words, the `SetupClassLoader` has no effect here, except complicating the code and consuming some memory.

---

Truly dynamically loaded code must not be referenced by the static code and to avoid such errors, the dynamic classes should not be accessible by the static code in the first place. But then, you’re trading the setup code for the code to implement the dynamic class loading which has to stay in memory.

So its rather unlikely to have a benefit, even if implemented correctly. Further, keep in mind that class unloading is an optional feature, so it might not even happen at all in a particular environment.

If you really have a large and complex user interface, you may instead consider the option to describe menus and UI layout etc. via XML or JSON files or similar description languages. Then, the code to parse the files and build the UI does not depend on the UI size. Text to be shown in the UI should be placed in resource files anyway, rather than the setup code, e.g. to allow translation or fixing mistakes without the need to rebuild the application.